# RegexKitLite problem with start of string

Tags: iphone, ios, regexkitlite

I'm trying to replace a character NOT AT THE START OF THE STRING, with itself followed by another character, using regexKitLite.

```
thisPlate = [sBasePlate 
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"([^\\^]%@)", thisChar] 
             withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\1%@", thisRep]
             ];
```

If **sBasePlate** is "temp", then **thisPlate** gets set to *emp*, but I'm expecting it to be *teemp*

So I'm trying to replace NOT THE START OF THE STRING, followed by **thisChar**, with that which has been matched followed by **thisRep**.

Have I got my backreferences wrong? Because that's what seems to be missing. It's adding in **thisRep**, but ignoring the initial match and not putting it back in with **\1**

Sorry if I've done something really stupid and obvious, this is my first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I solved it. I hate answering my own questions but someone else might make the same mistake as me, so the big stupid obvious thing I missed...

back references should be $ signs.

```
withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$1%@", prevRep]
```

That's how that string should be written.

Annoyingly the documentation here says that a back reference should be "\n":

http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/

But an example elsewhere shows $n. I should have guessed that. Oh well.